# Composer Packagist. How to define a package as stable?

Tags: laravel, package, composer-php

Im new to making packages with composer.

I am currently creating a package for laravel. 
My question is basically, how do I define a package as stable. Because at the moment I am unable to require my package because it is classified as dev and I have to use the @dev, which is not what I want to do.

My here is my github.

https://github.com/kevupton/bookings

and packagist:

https://packagist.org/packages/kevupton/bookings

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Get rid of

```
"minimum-stability": "dev"
```

You may also consider using git tags instead of specifying `version` manually.

Comment: tanks for that. addign the github coments and removing it from the composer.json really helped. its all good now

Comment: The minimum stability does not do anything. Tagging a version does.

Answer (score 3):

The `"minimum-stability":"anything"` doesn't affect using a package. It only affects packages being used INSIDE this package if it is used as the main package. When being used somewhere else, this setting is completely ignored by Composer to prevent unstable versions being installed if the main package does not allow them.

The only thing that is being used to identify a package stability is its version number.

If this is in the form "x.y.z" without any suffixes, it is stable.

More stability levels (in decreasing order) are "RC, "beta" and "alpha". All these still require tagged versions. Below them is "dev", which may also be a tagged version, but usually is a branch.

Comment: Here's how to tag https://stackoverflow.com/a/54204738/10126479