# How to create beta version of composer package?

Tags: php, git, composer-php

I have package and need publish it on packagist repository. I am using git as VCS and currently my package installable through composer.
Sometimes in composer.json we can see something like that:
`"version" : "1.0.0-beta2"`, or `"dev-master"`.

But i don't know how i can create beta and dev version of my package?
I don't know where i can provide type of my library (beta and dev version). Also, i don`t understand why in first case version type -beta2 presents as suffix, and in the second case (dev-master) version type present as prefix.

Can anyone explain?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're just tag names in your repository.

https://packagist.org/about

> Tag/version names should match 'X.Y.Z', or 'vX.Y.Z', with an optional
>   suffix for RC, beta, alpha or patch versions. Here are a few examples
>   of valid tag names:
>
> ```
> 1.0.0
> v1.0.0
> 1.10.5-RC1
> v4.4.4beta2
> v2.0.0-alpha
> v2.0.4-p1
> ```

As for `dev-master`:

> Branches will automatically appear as "dev" versions that are easily installable by anyone that wants to try your library's latest and greatest, but that does not mean you should not tag releases. The use of Semantic Versioning is strongly encouraged.

Comment: Can the suffix be anything? Is `1.5.0-blabla` also valid? And does the suffix gets evaluated by composer anyhow? I could imagine that is works if a certain version is required, but not with version constraint declarations. What does composer do if `1.5.* ` is specified for a package and the there are versions like `1.5.0`, `1.5.1`, `1.5.1-alpha`?

Comment: From [Composer Versions and Constraints: Stabilities](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#stabilities): *Composer recognizes the following stabilities (in order of stability): **dev**, **alpha**, **beta**, **RC**, and **stable** where RC stands for release candidate.* These may have numeric suffixes, eg 1.1.0-alpha2.